# Is there a first-order sentence that can distinguish cyclic and non-cyclic finite Abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, first-order-logic, abelian-groups

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be the class of all Abelian groups. It is easy to show that there is no first-order sentence $\varphi$ that can distinguish cyclic and non-cyclic groups in this setting.

Consider the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$, which is cyclic. By upward Löwenheim-Skolem, there exists a group $G$ with cardinality $\beth_1$ that is elementarily equivalent to $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. However, $G$ cannot be cyclic since any group with exactly one generator is countable.

Suppose, then, that we consider $\mathfrak{B}$, the class of all finite Abelian groups. Is there a sentence in the language of groups for $\mathfrak{B}$ that distinguishes cyclic and non-cyclic groups?

Comment: Not sure if this can be coded in first order,but I suspect it can: In a finite cyclic group, if $x$ and $y$ have the same order, then $x$ is a power of $y$ and $y$ is a power of $x$. In a noncyclic finite abelian group, there exist two elements $x$ and $y$ of the same order such that  if $x^a=y^b$, then $x^a=y^b=1$.

Comment: Note that both are false in the infinite cyclic group: both the generator and its square have the same order, but the generator is not a power of its square; and given any two nontrivial elements, they always have a common nontrivial power.

Comment: You can definitely distinguish them with a scheme $\varphi_n$.  A finite abelian group is cyclic if and only if $x^n=1$ never has more than $n$ distinct solutions.